# Perfect Synchronization with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working on a simple audio visualization application that uses a Web Audio API analyzer to pull frequency data, as in [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH6-SW14). Expectedly, the more visual elements I add to my canvases, the more latency there is between the audio and the yielded visual results.

Is there a standard approach to accounting for this latency? I can imagine a lookahead technique that buffers the upcoming audio data. I could work with synchronizing the JavaScript and Web Audio clocks, but I'm convinced that there's a much more intuitive answer. Perhaps it is as straightforward as playing the audio aloud with a slight delay (although this is not nearly as comprehensive).

The [dancer.js library](http://jsantell.github.io/dancer.js/) seems to have the same problem (always has a very subtle delay), whereas other applications seem to have solved the lag issue entirely. I have insofar been unable to pinpoint the technical difference. [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/visualizer) seems to handle this a bit better, but it would be nice to build from scratch.

Any methodologies to point me in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, the MIDI protocol is made for it, you should maybe look this way?

Comment: Hello  XLXMXNT, how did you solve your problem? I'm seeing lag in my example here: https://trusktr.io/polydance (ignore the HTTPS warning, just click through to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find some answers to precise audio timing in this article:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

[SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) uses this approach to enable smooth looping, but still uses javascript timers for delayed playback.  This may not help you sync the audio timing with the animation timing.  When I built the music visualizer example for SoundJS I found I had to play around with the different values for fft size and tick frequency to get good performance.  I also needed to cache a single shape and reuse it with scaling to have performant graphics.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Really appreciate the SoundJS insight. It may indeed be a combination of techniques that altogether reduce the processing overhead. However, it appears, somewhat, that the song with the visualization is laggy for the first play, but if you stop it and play again from the beginning (without refreshing the page) the timing is basically perfect. May be something to look into.

Answer (score 3):

I'm concerned when you say the more visual elements you add to your canvases, the more latency you get in audio.  That shouldn't really happen quite like that.  Are your canvases being animated using requestAnimationFrame?  What's your frame rate like?

You can't, technically speaking, synchronize the JS and Web Audio clocks - the Web Audio clock is the audio hardware clock, which is literally running off a different clock crystal than the system clock (on many systems, at least).  The vast majority of web audio (ScriptProcessorNodes being the major exception) shouldn't have additional latency introduced when your main UI thread becomes a bit more congested).

If the problem is the analysis just seems to lag (i.e. the visuals are consistently "behind" the audio), it could just be the inherent lag in the FFT processing.  You can reduce the FFT size in the Analyser, although you'll get less definition then; to fake up fixing it, you can also run all the audio through a delay node to get it to re-sync with the visuals.

Also, you may find that the "smoothing" parameter on the Analyser makes it less time-precise - try turning that down.

Comment: I am using requestAnimationFrame, and I may have been unclear in that it is the graphics that are falling behind the music. The audio continues as-is but the visuals lag slightly behind, if only marginally.